# Get filenames from current dir, save into char ** array, glob, C, seg fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, valgrind, glob, arrays

I wrote a simple code to get all filenames from current directory and save them into char **array. But my code gives me segmentation fault, and some valgrind errors.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <glob.h>

char **getFilenames()
{
    char **filenames = NULL;
    glob_t data;
    unsigned int i;

    switch( glob("./*.*", 0, NULL, &data ) )
    {
        case 0:
            break;
        case GLOB_NOSPACE:
            printf( "Out of memory\n" );
            break;
        case GLOB_ABORTED:
            printf( "Reading error\n" );
            break;
        case GLOB_NOMATCH:
            printf( "No files found\n" );
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    filenames = malloc(sizeof(char*)*data.gl_pathc);
    for(i=0; i<data.gl_pathc; i++)
    {
        filenames[i] = data.gl_pathv[i];
    }
    globfree( &data );
    return filenames;
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    char **filenames = getFilenames();
    unsigned int i = 0;
    for(i=0; filenames[i] != NULL; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", filenames[i]);
    }

    free(filenames);

    return 0;
}
```

Valgrind's output:

```
==3936== Invalid read of size 8
==3936==    at 0x40077F: main (in /home/mazix/Desktop/tests/filenames)
==3936==  Address 0x5207670 is 0 bytes after a block of size 608 alloc'd
==3936==    at 0x4C2CD7B: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3936==    by 0x4006C9: getFilenames (in /home/mazix/Desktop/tests/filenames)
==3936==    by 0x400737: main (in /home/mazix/Desktop/tests/filenames)
==3936== 
==3936== 
==3936== FILE DESCRIPTORS: 3 open at exit.
==3936== Open file descriptor 2: /dev/pts/3
==3936==    <inherited from parent>
==3936== 
==3936== Open file descriptor 1: /dev/pts/3
==3936==    <inherited from parent>
==3936== 
==3936== Open file descriptor 0: /dev/pts/3
==3936==    <inherited from parent>
==3936== 
==3936== 
==3936== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3936==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3936==   total heap usage: 155 allocs, 155 frees, 35,964 bytes allocated
==3936== 
==3936== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==3936== 
==3936== ERROR SUMMARY: 2204 errors from 12 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
==3936== 
==3936== 1 errors in context 1 of 12:
==3936== Invalid read of size 8
==3936==    at 0x40077F: main (in /home/mazix/Desktop/tests/filenames)
==3936==  Address 0x5207670 is 0 bytes after a block of size 608 alloc'd
==3936==    at 0x4C2CD7B: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3936==    by 0x4006C9: getFilenames (in /home/mazix/Desktop/tests/filenames)
==3936==    by 0x400737: main (in /home/mazix/Desktop/tests/filenames)
==3936== 
==3936== 
==3936== 13 errors in context 2 of 12:
==3936== Invalid read of size 8
==3936==    at 0x4EC13A3: __GI_mempcpy (memcpy.S:123)
==3936==    by 0x4EAEB11: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1329)
==3936==    by 0x4EA4F5F: puts (ioputs.c:41)
==3936==    by 0x400768: main (in /home/mazix/Desktop/tests/filenames)
==3936==  Address 0x5205b7a is 10 bytes inside a block of size 19 free'd
==3936==    at 0x4C2BA6C: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3936==    by 0x4EF7DD3: globfree (glob.c:1278)
==3936==    by 0x400718: getFilenames (in /home/mazix/Desktop/tests/filenames)
==3936==    by 0x400737: main (in /home/mazix/Desktop/tests/filenames)
==3936== 
==3936== 
==3936== 13 errors in context 3 of 12:
==3936== Invalid read of size 8
==3936==    at 0x4EC13A0: __GI_mempcpy (memcpy.S:122)
==3936==    by 0x4EAEB11: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1329)
==3936==    by 0x4EA4F5F: puts (ioputs.c:41)
==3936==    by 0x400768: main (in /home/mazix/Desktop/tests/filenames)
==3936==  Address 0x5205b72 is 2 bytes inside a block of size 19 free'd
==3936==    at 0x4C2BA6C: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3936==    by 0x4EF7DD3: globfree (glob.c:1278)
==3936==    by 0x400718: getFilenames (in /home/mazix/Desktop/tests/filenames)
==3936==    by 0x400737: main (in /home/mazix/Desktop/tests/filenames)
==3936== 
==3936== 
==3936== 16 errors in context 4 of 12:
==3936== Invalid read of size 1
==3936==    at 0x4EB0ADD: _IO_default_xsputn (genops.c:481)
==3936==    by 0x4EAEBB2: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1364)
==3936==    by 0x4EA4F5F: puts (ioputs.c:41)
==3936==    by 0x400768: main (in /home/mazix/Desktop/tests/filenames)
==3936==  Address 0x5206280 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 17 free'd
==3936==    at 0x4C2BA6C: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3936==    by 0x4EF7DD3: globfree (glob.c:1278)
==3936==    by 0x400718: getFilenames (in /home/mazix/Desktop/tests/filenames)
==3936==    by 0x400737: main (in /home/mazix/Desktop/tests/filenames)
==3936== 
==3936== 
==3936== 26 errors in context 5 of 12:
==3936== Invalid read of size 1
==3936==    at 0x4EC134B: __GI_mempcpy (memcpy.S:71)
==3936==    by 0x4EAEB11: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1329)
==3936==    by 0x4EA4F5F: puts (ioputs.c:41)
==3936==    by 0x400768: main (in /home/mazix/Desktop/tests/filenames)
==3936==  Address 0x5206f50 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 18 free'd
==3936==    at 0x4C2BA6C: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3936==    by 0x4EF7DD3: globfree (glob.c:1278)
==3936==    by 0x400718: getFilenames (in /home/mazix/Desktop/tests/filenames)
==3936==    by 0x400737: main (in /home/mazix/Desktop/tests/filenames)
==3936== 
==3936== 
==3936== 32 errors in context 6 of 12:
==3936== Invalid read of size 4
==3936==    at 0x4EC136E: __GI_mempcpy (memcpy.S:95)
==3936==    by 0x4EAEB11: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1329)
==3936==    by 0x4EA4F5F: puts (ioputs.c:41)
==3936==    by 0x400768: main (in /home/mazix/Desktop/tests/filenames)
==3936==  Address 0x5206db2 is 2 bytes inside a block of size 23 free'd
==3936==    at 0x4C2BA6C: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3936==    by 0x4EF7DD3: globfree (glob.c:1278)
==3936==    by 0x400718: getFilenames (in /home/mazix/Desktop/tests/filenames)
==3936==    by 0x400737: main (in /home/mazix/Desktop/tests/filenames)
==3936== 
==3936== 
==3936== 50 errors in context 7 of 12:
==3936== Invalid read of size 2
==3936==    at 0x4EC135B: __GI_mempcpy (memcpy.S:83)
==3936==    by 0x4EAEB11: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1329)
==3936==    by 0x4EA4F5F: puts (ioputs.c:41)
==3936==    by 0x400768: main (in /home/mazix/Desktop/tests/filenames)
==3936==  Address 0x5205b70 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 19 free'd
==3936==    at 0x4C2BA6C: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3936==    by 0x4EF7DD3: globfree (glob.c:1278)
==3936==    by 0x400718: getFilenames (in /home/mazix/Desktop/tests/filenames)
==3936==    by 0x400737: main (in /home/mazix/Desktop/tests/filenames)
==3936== 
==3936== 
==3936== 61 errors in context 8 of 12:
==3936== Invalid read of size 8
==3936==    at 0x4EC137F: __GI_mempcpy (memcpy.S:107)
==3936==    by 0x4EAEB11: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1329)
==3936==    by 0x4EA4F5F: puts (ioputs.c:41)
==3936==    by 0x400768: main (in /home/mazix/Desktop/tests/filenames)
==3936==  Address 0x52073c5 is 5 bytes inside a block of size 14 free'd
==3936==    at 0x4C2BA6C: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3936==    by 0x4EF7DD3: globfree (glob.c:1278)
==3936==    by 0x400718: getFilenames (in /home/mazix/Desktop/tests/filenames)
==3936==    by 0x400737: main (in /home/mazix/Desktop/tests/filenames)
==3936== 
==3936== 
==3936== 75 errors in context 9 of 12:
==3936== Invalid read of size 1
==3936==    at 0x4EAEBDD: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1311)
==3936==    by 0x4EA4F5F: puts (ioputs.c:41)
==3936==    by 0x400768: main (in /home/mazix/Desktop/tests/filenames)
==3936==  Address 0x5205b81 is 17 bytes inside a block of size 19 free'd
==3936==    at 0x4C2BA6C: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3936==    by 0x4EF7DD3: globfree (glob.c:1278)
==3936==    by 0x400718: getFilenames (in /home/mazix/Desktop/tests/filenames)
==3936==    by 0x400737: main (in /home/mazix/Desktop/tests/filenames)
==3936== 
==3936== 
==3936== 76 errors in context 10 of 12:
==3936== Invalid read of size 1
==3936==    at 0x4C2D7C2: __GI_strlen (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3936==    by 0x4EA4ECB: puts (ioputs.c:36)
==3936==    by 0x400768: main (in /home/mazix/Desktop/tests/filenames)
==3936==  Address 0x5206280 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 17 free'd
==3936==    at 0x4C2BA6C: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3936==    by 0x4EF7DD3: globfree (glob.c:1278)
==3936==    by 0x400718: getFilenames (in /home/mazix/Desktop/tests/filenames)
==3936==    by 0x400737: main (in /home/mazix/Desktop/tests/filenames)
==3936== 
==3936== 
==3936== 875 errors in context 11 of 12:
==3936== Invalid read of size 1
==3936==    at 0x4EAEBF9: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1311)
==3936==    by 0x4EA4F5F: puts (ioputs.c:41)
==3936==    by 0x400768: main (in /home/mazix/Desktop/tests/filenames)
==3936==  Address 0x5205b80 is 16 bytes inside a block of size 19 free'd
==3936==    at 0x4C2BA6C: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3936==    by 0x4EF7DD3: globfree (glob.c:1278)
==3936==    by 0x400718: getFilenames (in /home/mazix/Desktop/tests/filenames)
==3936==    by 0x400737: main (in /home/mazix/Desktop/tests/filenames)
==3936== 
==3936== 
==3936== 966 errors in context 12 of 12:
==3936== Invalid read of size 1
==3936==    at 0x4C2D7D4: __GI_strlen (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3936==    by 0x4EA4ECB: puts (ioputs.c:36)
==3936==    by 0x400768: main (in /home/mazix/Desktop/tests/filenames)
==3936==  Address 0x5206281 is 1 bytes inside a block of size 17 free'd
==3936==    at 0x4C2BA6C: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3936==    by 0x4EF7DD3: globfree (glob.c:1278)
==3936==    by 0x400718: getFilenames (in /home/mazix/Desktop/tests/filenames)
==3936==    by 0x400737: main (in /home/mazix/Desktop/tests/filenames)
==3936==    by 0x400737: main (in /home/mazix/Desktop/tests/filenames)
==3936== 
--3936-- 
--3936-- used_suppression:      2 dl-hack3-cond-1
==3936== 
==3936== ERROR SUMMARY: 2204 errors from 12 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

Comment: What do you think happens with the path pointers when you call `globfree`?

Comment: Build with debug information (`-g` flag for GCC/clang) and run again. Then you will get line numbers in Valgrind call-stack. Or run in a debugger and it will stop when the crash happens, and you can examine and walk up the call stack and examine variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not copied the file name, but just set the pointer from the data.

```
filenames[i] = data.gl_pathv[i];
```

This is incorrect. You can use

```
filenames[i] = strdup(data.gl_pathv[i]);
```

You need to later free this duped string in main as below.

```
for(i=0; filenames[i] != NULL; i++)
{
    printf("%s\n", filenames[i]);
    free(filenames[i]);
}
```

Another issue is noted here. The last element is not set to NULL.

```
for(i=0; filenames[i] != NULL; i++)
```

Allocate an additional pointer and set it to NULL as below.

```
filenames = malloc(sizeof(char*)*(data.gl_pathc+1));
for(i=0; i<data.gl_pathc; i++)
{
    filenames[i] = strdup(data.gl_pathv[i]);
}
filenames[i] = NULL;
```

Comment: Still have `segmentation fault`

Comment: Where is the segmentation fault now?

Comment: `Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__strlen_sse2 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/../strlen.S:31
31      ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/../strlen.S: no such file or directory.`

Comment: Ok, its ALMOST ok :) I have a memory leak with your code, dont know where: http://pastie.org/private/bvxefsliybtloi6crtvtq and heres full code: http://pastie.org/private/nhh1fyztyftsc3ykzk34a

Comment: Last line before return from main is free(filenames); in you code, but free(filenames[i]); in the above link. Former one is correct.